# RDP login works when using Android App, but now when using Windows

Tags: windows, authentication, rdp, login, windows-authentication

I am trying to connect to my work machine using RDP.

Using my Android Phone I can connect to it. It shows up in the list and I fill in my details like so: COMPANYNAME\USERNAME. Then I enter the password that I use to log into the work machine with, and all is well.

Now, I go to my Windows 10 PC (NOT the work machine!), I go to the network menu in the explorer,I see the Work machine, I right-click and select the "remote desktop connection" button.

I fill in my username (COMPANYNAME\USERNAME) and the password, just like with Android.. And after a while of "securing remote connection" it stops and errors out with "login attempt failed".

I am very confused. Why does it work on my Android phone and not on my Windows PC?

Comment: What's the exact error, perhaps a screenshot.  I don't recognize that particular phrase as a common error (I'd expect "Unable to establish connection"), but when I do RDP as you have from a non-domain machine to a domain machine it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I had to put these 2 things in my RDP file:

```
enablecredsspsupport:i:0
authentication level:i:2
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62330026/3013479